# Using InputStream to read file from internal storage

Tags: android, inputstream

I've searched for a couple days, and all I find is using bufferedReader to read from a file on internal storage.  Is it not possible to use InputStream to read from a file on internal storage?

```
private void dailyInput()
{    
    InputStream in;
    in = this.getAsset().open("file.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(in));
    in.close();
}
```

I use this now  with `input.next(`) to search my file for the data that I need. It all works fine, but I would like to save new files to internal storage and read from them without changing everything to bufferedReader.  Is this possible or do I need to bite the bullet and change everything?  FYI I don't need to write, only read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a file.

```
String FILENAME = "file.txt";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

to read

```
void OpenFileDialog(String file) {

    //Read file in Internal Storage
    FileInputStream fis;
    String content = "";
    try {
        fis = openFileInput(file);
        byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
        while (fis.read(input) != -1) {
        }
        content += new String(input);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`content` will Contain your File Data.

Comment: To access a file on internal storage of the device, do I need to set the FILENAME string to the path of file.txt on the device?  Also, fis.read(); can only read into int?

Comment: fis.read() can only read into an int.  Also, I get a runtime error using this method (probably doing the path wrong).  I'm using scanner to search the document for the data I need.  This allows me to read one string at a time. Is it not possible to use Scanner with a file from internal storage?

Comment: k. I am Editing my Answer see it

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have me on the right track. One more question, how do I specify the file path?

Comment: From what I've read, you can't read from internal memory using FileInputStream. The file path is /storage/emulated/0/myapp/S050213.txt

Comment: can get you? Can you be more specific.

Comment: I have reports that are generated by a server. I want to save the reports to my device's internal memory and search and pull out the data I need in a way similar to the code I posted. The way I have it now gets the file from assets, but I would like to get the file from internal memory instead. What I have found so far is that I have to use either File instead of FileInputStream, bufferedreader, or both.

Comment: My idea of internal storage seems to be wrong, my apologies. Your answer answered the question I asked, I just asked the wrong question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Using available() to allocate memory is not correct as explained in documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available()

"Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream. "

Answer (score 0):

You may try following code when you face a condition to read a file from a subfolder in internal storage. Sometimes you may get problems with *openFileInput* whey you trying to passing context.
here is the function.

```
    public String getDataFromFile(File file){  
     StringBuilder data= new StringBuilder();  
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String singleLine;
        while ((singleLine= br.readLine()) != null) {
            data.append(singleLine);
            data.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
        return data.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        return ""+e;
    }
}
```