# Android saving file to internal memory, something goes wrong

Tags: android, save

I'm trying to save variables on a file, and it seems as though the saving process is fine, but it cannot find a string I saved. Can anyone help me?

```
EditText Strength;
String getstrengthvalue;
String filename = "file.txt";

public void onSave(View view) {

    String string = "Hello world!";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(getstrengthvalue.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public void onLoad(View view) {
    try {
        InputStream is = openFileInput(filename);
        is.read(getstrengthvalue.getBytes());
        Strength.setText(getstrengthvalue);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `openFileInput(filename);`. That should be `InputStream is = openFileInput(filename);`. Then `read` from the stream `is`.

Comment: where do i need to put the read and is commands, and how do use them. Thanks!

Comment: There where you want to read from the opened stream. Just compare with how you used `write()` before to write. And further google.

Comment: still not working... but thanks anyway!

Comment: So still not working and you do not show the code you tried. It looks as if you dont want to be helped.

Comment: Sorry but i will not try to read code in comments? Do you like to inspect code in comments? Use your post.

Comment: edited it. Thanks a lot man

Comment: You have not done any googling at all is it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375944/using-inputstream-to-read-file-from-internal-storage